# Discord.py @client.commands() unable to execute but @client.events can execute

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

While making a bot for the video game VALORANT out of fun, I realised I could not get the client.commands to work at all while the client.event for on_message still works

I actually have no idea what is wrong

Things I tried doing:

- Changed the command_prefix to a single variable (originally it had multiple command_prefixes)
- Using code from a bot that does work. (Ping Command)
- Went to the developer portal to see if I gave enough permissions to the bot (I gave it admin)
- Reduced number of aliases
- changed aliases to name
- Imported asyncio
- put in print functions to determine if the await was the one not working or not (it didnt print out the text i set which i assume is the bot not recognising the command entirely)

So far nothing works, is there sth I missed on a fundamental level?

```
import discord
import random

from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=['v:'])

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(name = "VALORANT"))
    print("Initiated!")

# commands that cannot work
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    print("if this shows up then it works lmao")
    await ctx.send(f"Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")

@client.command(aliases = ['RAgent', 'ragent', 'RandomAgent', 'randomagent'])
async def Random_Agent_Selection(ctx):
    print("if this shows up then it works lmao")
    Agents = ['Breach',
              'Brimstone',
              'Cypher',
              'Jett',
              'Killjoy',
              'Omen',
              'Phoenix',
              'Raze',
              'Reyna',
              'Sage',
              'Skye',
              'Sova',
              'Viper']
    await ctx.channel.send(f"Random Agent: {random.choice(Agents)}")

# event that DOES work
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "valorant" in message.content.lower() and message.author.id != 750663559695958016: 
    #id = bot id so it wont infitely loop the command
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send("The Valorant corporation is waiting for you")

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `process_commands` at the end of `on_message` event.

Read More: [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working)

Below is the revised code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "valorant" in message.content.lower() and message.author.id != 750663559695958016: 
    #id = bot id so it wont infitely loop the command
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send("The Valorant corporation is waiting for you")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```